# Is it a waste to implement HashMap via PDAs when the value type is only a bool?

Tags: rust, pda, rent

When writing smart contracts for EVM chains, I can define a `mapping(address => bool)`. When it comes to Solana, I think I can only use PDAs to achieve the same thing? Is my understanding correct?

If correct, then is it a waste to store only a bool (1 byte only) in an account? Since Solana account takes at least the intrinsic 128 bytes, if I only store 1 byte as my data, then 128/129 (i.e., 99.2%) of my rent is for the intrinsic bytes. Feels like a kind of waste?

If not correct, then is there any other approach to achieve `mapping(address => bool)` on Solana?

---

(Edit) My use case: I'm developing a Solana program. Users can call this program to mark an NFT (i.e., the NFT mint address) as "used". Whether an NFT is "used" or not is tracked by my program, so I need something like `mapping(address => bool)`.

Comment: Could you explain your use case a bit more? There might be more efficient solutions but it really depends on the use case

Comment: @dr497 I've edited my question and explained my use case. Could you please have a look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach you are describing given your use case is reasonable - assuming the seeds of the PDA would be the mint of the NFT. This is clearly the most efficient way to know if an NFT is marked as used and comes with a simple resolution. However, consider the following situation

- Alice marks the NFT as "used"
- Alice transfers/sells the NFT to Bob

If the account only contains a boolean value you won't be able to keep track of this ownership change and based on your business logic this might create issues. Adding the public key of the owner marking the NFT as "used" in the PDA derivation would solve this issue but the mapping is less straight forward. You could also store the public key of the owner in the account instead of a boolean value - but it increases the account size by 32 bytes.

The alternatives I had in mind were something where the seeds would be the owner public key and the account would be extended/reduced by adding NFT mint public key which might be more efficient for users marking a lot of NFT as used. However, this approach introduces more complexity.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on who should pay the rent and how many accounts you plan to have.

Depending on the number of users/keys you have and if you want to pay the rent, you could store a considerably large array in one account, like:

```
#[account(zero_copy)]
#[repr(C)]
pub struct UserLog {
    pub used_keys: [LogEntry; 1024]

}

#[derive(Pod, Zeroable, Default, AnchorSerialize, AnchorDeserialize, Clone, Copy)]
#[repr(C)]
pub struct LogEntry {
    pub key: Pubkey,
    pub some_val: u8, // Note: bool is not zero-copy safe
    pub _reserved0: [u8; 7]
}
```

This would be relatively cheap, fewer accounts, and if you sort on insertion, likely better performance. The use-case for PDAs here would be if your data is too large to fit this way, because then the rent cost (which as you noted as higher because of more account overhead) is shifted onto the user when they init the individual PDAs.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've really learned new ways of thinking from you. But both answers are great and teach me a lot, while I can accept only one answer. Seems that in Solana world, "array"-like data structures are more useful than in EVM world. I guess it's because Solana's data storage cost (i.e., the rent) is lower, and Solana charges users the transaction fee based on signature count instead of hardware execution units. In this way, sometimes we don't need to find the data of interest within O(1) time, so we don't have to use a "hashmap"-like data structures.

Answer (score 1):

As another option, if you just need a small piece of metadata, you might be able to use the token-metadata extension in token-2022: https://spl.solana.com/token-2022/extensions#metadata

If you give metadata update authority to a PDA of your program, then you can use a custom field to mark your bool https://spl.solana.com/token-2022/extensions#example-add-a-custom-field

With this approach, your storage costs are minimized.

Comment: Oh this approach seems really great and space saving! But a condition must be met: the NFT mint account is created by Token 2022 Program instead of the Token Program. We can't apply this approach to NFTs that are created by the classical Token Program, right? Since those NFT mint accounts don't have metadata in their own accounts. (Their metadata is stored in a PDA created by Metaplex's Metadata Program I think?)

Comment: Correct, you'll need to use token-2022 for your mints if you want to go with this approach. I think Metaplex supports token-2022 now, so you could do both if needed!